# JSCS Punctuator

Tags: reactjs, import, ecmascript-6, jscs

I have a difficulty with setting up JSCS to work with JSX/React and ES6 (stage-0). It throws such errors:

```
Expected end of node list but "Punctuator" found at ./src/base/react/architecture/components/Dummy.component.jsx :
     1 |import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
--------^
```

and

```
Expected end of node list but "Punctuator" found at ./src/base/react/architecture/utils/redux-ext.js :
     1 |import React from 'react';
--------^
     2 |import Immutable from 'immutable';
     3 |import * as reactRedux from 'react-redux';
```

I wasn't able either to fix it or to find the cause of this problem.

My configuration is:

```
{
  "preset": "airbnb",
  "validateIndentation": 4,
  "fileExtensions": [
    ".js",
    ".jsx"
  ],
  "maxErrors": -1,
  "excludeFiles": [
    "**/ammap.js",
    "**/worldHigh.js",
    "**/worldLow.js",
    "node_modules/*",
    "**/assets/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check that you have latest (3.0) version of JSCS.
Also, consider switching to [ESlint](http://eslint.org/), because JSCS is not maintained anymore and ESlint is a recommended mirgation way.

Comment: I have v3.0.7 and moving to eslint is now costly since it finds a lot of errors on the same preset (Airbnb) whereas JSCS only like 10 of the kind mentioned above. I'm confused about that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After some digging, I nailed it down to the semi-colon in my static propTypes. I am on JSCS 3.0.7 as well.
Current workaround (still looking for a better fix):

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

//jscs:disable requireSemicolons
//unfortunately had to disable semicolons
const SomeComponent = WrappedComponent => class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        somePropType: React.PropTypes.func,
    } //semicolon here caused the 'Punctuator' error 

    constructor (props) {
        super(props); ....
```